# Error when creating a custum item operation in Symfony 6.2 on Api Platform

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I try to create a custum controller in my User entity for Api Platform
I get a 200 HTTP request, but i don't have any date return
I don't have any error but no result.
I have follow the official doctumentation of api platform: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/#alternative-method

This is my User entity:

```
// App\Entity\User.php

<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiProperty;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Get;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Post;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Put;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Delete;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\GetCollection;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use App\Entity\Session;
use DateTime;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\MaxDepth;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource(
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['user']],
    operations: [
        new Get(),
        new Post(),
        new Put(),
        new Delete(),
        new Get(
            name: 'contact',
            routeName: 'user_get_contact'
        ),

    ]
)]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[ApiProperty(identifier: false)]
    #[Groups('user')]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 180, unique: true)]
    #[Groups('user')]
    private ?string $email = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups('user')]
    private array $roles = [];

    #[ORM\Column(length: 10, unique: true)]
    #[ApiProperty(identifier: true)]
    #[Groups(['user'])]
    private ?string $name= null;
...
```

My controller for the function

```
// App\Controller\userController.php

<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use ApiPlatform\Serializer\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Attribute\AsController;

#[AsController]
class UserController extends AbstractController
{

    public function getContact(string $name)
    {
        $array = ["hello", "world", $name];
        return $array;
    }
}
```

My router

```
// config\routes.yaml


user_get_contact:
  path: /api/users/{name}/contact
  methods: ["GET"]
  defaults:
    _controller: App\Controller\UserController::getContact
    _api_resource_class: App\Entity\User
    _api_operation_name: get_contact
```